# Connect two embedded devices with USB host with Ethernet?

Tags: usb, ethernet, bridge, host

I need to connect two microprocessors that only have USB host, not OTG or client.

Obviously I would like to connect them as directly and quickly (ie 10's of Mbit up to 100) as possible.  A USB to serial to USB bridge is simply not fast enough.  Also [Prolific's PL-25A1](http://prolificusa.com/portfolio/pl-25a1-hi-speed-usb-host-to-host-bridge-controller/) looks ideal but is specific for windows whereas both of my platforms are running linux.

My current thought is to implement a USB to Ethernet to USB solution.  For example if I used an SMSC LAN9512 then I would get my ethernet connection.  The LAN9512 has built in MAC and PHY.

My question is how much of a physical interface do I need to implement?

Similar to TI's [AN-1519](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla088a/snla088a.pdf) as referenced in [this exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/90330/connecting-two-ethernet-phy-without-magnetics).
can I get away with some 33nF caps?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the micros have any other ports - serial, I2C SPI or even spare GPIO pins? And must it be Ethernet? How far do they need to communicate? Do they need to communicate over the internet?

Comment: Are the two micros on the same board or are they in separate devices?

Comment: Can you support simple USB wireless adapters? -- http://www.monoprice.com/Product?seq=1&format=2&p_id=8072&CAWELAID=1329456150&CAGPSPN=pla&gclid=Cj0KEQjwx4yfBRCt2rrAs-P5vtkBEiQAOdFXbRDvCWEhQ--5uG2XLKhvfpJdN-vE8njA9WtdkerfyCAaAp018P8HAQ

Comment: Unfortunately I only have USB exposed on the one microprocessor.  It is part of one of our existing products and so I have to work with what I have.  The second micro is being added as a daughter board which will be connected with a board to board header.  They have common power though with seperate PMICs.  The wireless USB is an intriguing suggestion; I will look into that - starting on the monoprice site :)

Comment: I should add that the second module is a Raspberry Pi Compute module.  That should really open up the discussion.  Maybe it can enumerate as a USB client (Ethernet port?) and I just missed that fact.

Comment: But I need to use the USB port on the PI for external storage so currently it would host the ethernet port and a USB to SATA bridge.

Comment: I would think USB-ethernet would work (that's what is on the model B pi anyway), but wouldn't it be simpler and cheaper to just buy off-the-shelf USB-ethernet dongles?

Comment: Also note that those USB file transfer cable chips are typically treated as a type of network interface under Linux - ie, supported, and working, but in a way not compatible with the way Windows uses them.

Answer (score 1):

There is one variant with a minimal hardware, if you are (self, or friending) a brutal embedded low-level system programmer.

DISCLAMER: I never checked this in practice, it's all about theoretical speculation.

- First and simple, connect the MCUs directly via the USB transceiver interface lines (`D+` & `D-`) providing the respecting static voltage levels necessary to properly detect the mode (full speed or high speed) of the bus, by the appropriate pull-down resistors.

  [image]
- Second and complex, program the [OHCI/EHCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Host_Controller_Interface) unit of the MCU and the responsible driver to only send/receive "naked" USB data type packets and eliminate all other activities.

As a result, you'll (probably) get a half-duplex channel controllable by something like CDMA/CA (i.e. Collision Avoidance) access method employed in wireless networking.

---

There is another variant with stronger hardware but standard software.

- Use a pair of USB FIFO ICs (like FT245R or FT232R in FIFO mode because it has a clock output) controllable by a low-cost CPLD.

  [image]

As a result, you'll get a full-duplex channel controllable by something like PPP.