# Connecting two ethernet ports back to back

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, ethernet, rmii, rgmii

Suppose, I am connecting the copper ports of 2 PHYs in back-to-back mode in the same board (using capacitive coupling technique), should the TX pair of one PHY be connected to the Rx pair of the other PHY or should it be vice versa?

Can someone please confirm?

Also, while connecting the digital section of the PHY to the MAC, I am using the RGMII interface.

In that case, according to this wiki article [RGMII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media-independent_interface#RGMII), TXC should be connected to RXC of MAC and TXCTL should be connected to RXCTL, right?

But whereas, if I am using the RMII interface, then TX_EN should be connected to CRS_DV , right? Please help

Comment: Suppose you are connecting two Ethernet devices together with a standard cable, are you connecting TX to TX, or TX to RX?

Comment: I am connecting TX to RX

Comment: @Justme, am i right? Could you help to answer my questions?

Comment: Assuming your phys have MDIX, it shouldn’t matter how you connect the two pairs. You really should take you time a research the datasheets and basics of ethernet thoroughly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting two Ethernet PHY without magnetics?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/90330/connecting-two-ethernet-phy-without-magnetics)